# Keep tkinter Progressbar running until a file is created

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, tkinter, progress-bar

I'm trying to put a info popup window to the user to advise him that a file is being created and that he must wait until it's created. I've a `master` frame that creates a `popup` window that shows the `Progressbar` with a message. This `popup`window must be destroyed as soon as the file has been created on the system.

This is my try:

```
import os
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

class UI(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        popup = Toplevel(self)
        txt = Label(popup, text="Please wait until the file is created").grid(row=0, column=0)
        progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(popup, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode='indeterminate')
        progressbar.grid(row=1, column=0)
        progressbar.start()

        self.checkfile()

        progressbar.stop()
        popup.destroy()

    def checkfile(self):
        while os.path.exists("myfile.txt") == False:
            print "not created yet"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    aplicacion = UI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

The problem is that the UI get's freezed and I can't see any window. I think I must use `Threads` to solve this problem right? Do I've to make two threads, one for the UI and the other one for the `checkfile` function, or with one is enough?

It would be highly appreciated if someone could add the `Threads` to my code to make it work as I've never use them and I'm totally lost.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while` loop cause the UI unreponsive.

Use [`Widget.after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) instead to periodically `checkfile` method.

```
def initUI(self):
    self.popup = popup = Toplevel(self)
    Label(popup, text="Please wait until the file is created").grid(
        row=0, column=0)
    self.progressbar = progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(popup,
        orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode='indeterminate')
    progressbar.grid(row=1, column=0)
    progressbar.start()
    self.checkfile()

def checkfile(self):
    if os.path.exists("myfile.txt"):
        print 'found it'
        self.progressbar.stop()
        self.popup.destroy()
    else:
        print 'not created yet'
        self.after(100, self.checkfile) # Call this method after 100 ms.
```

What modified:

- Used `after` instead of `while` loop.
- Made `progressbar`, `popup` accessible in `checkfile` method by making them instance attribute.
- Moved `progressbar.stop`, `popup.destroy` to `checkfile` method.

Comment: I have the same problem. What is 'self'? I simply can't find the answer!

Comment: @LukeDinkler, I recommend you to read [**Classes - Python tutorial**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html). In short, `self` is the first parameter of instance method.