# File Creation progress bar

Tags: python, file, user-interface, tkinter, progress-bar

I am making a small GUI that creates files when users import data. The function that creates the files is initiated when a particular button is clicked. The file gets put into a folder that the user chooses. I want a progress bar to be displayed during the process of the file being created. When the user imports data, the data file gets appended to a global list called `i_list`, and the functions in my GUI act on the data that's imported via this list.

I've done quite a bit of digging but can't seem to find any tips with regards to file creation and progress bars. Any tips or advice on how to do this? Here's the code I have:

```
i_lst = []
o_lst = []
created_files = []


class MainApplication(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Year (YYYY)", font=MEDIUM_FONT, justify = "center")
        label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = (60,0), pady = (40))

        #Bunch of Labels and Buttons
        #...


        button4 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Make my File!", command = self.FileMaker)
        button4.grid(row = 5, column = 1, padx = (8,10), ipadx = 15, pady = (0,20)) 

    def FileMaker(self):
        ...     

root = tk.Tk()
MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
root.minsize(width = 400, height = 500)
root.wm_title("File Maker")
center(root)
root.resizable(0,0)
root.iconbitmap('Treetog-I-Documents.ico')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: is `FileMaker` something that takes a long time? What does it do? Does it run in a separate thread or process?

Comment: Regards progress bar - have a look at this: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36516497/python-tkinter-simple-updating-progress-bar)

Comment: even more relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113207/keep-tkinter-progressbar-running-until-a-file-is-created